# Trying to use a variation on the name of a parent page serving up a .net user control as the SelectMethod for a datasource

Tags: c#, .net, objectdatasource, ascx

I am trying to build a reusable control (ascx) that can be used in multiple aspx pages. I have a datasource in the control which has a SelectMethod. Id like to use the calling page name (minus the extension) as the name of the SelectMethod - which can be looked up elsewhere.

Not sure how I would access this information from the ascx page. Was hoping something like this pseudo-code would work:

`<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="Parent.pagename()" TypeName="BlahBlah"></asp:ObjectDataSource>`

Where pagename() is a function in the .ascx.cs file returning the parent aspx page name as a string which can be looked up as the SelectMethod elsewhere in the ObjectContextFacadeManager in the BLL (its a large behemoth application - only half of which I am aware of).

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value you're looking for using the `AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath`. To output it you may have to use code-behind, though, because using inline-script, such as:

```
SelectMethod="<%Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath%>"
```

Won't work as the attribute value of a control with `runat="server"` (IIRC).

So, on load, or some other event, you could set this programmatically:

```
Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  SelectMethod = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
    Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath);
}
```

Comment: Thats great Grant. Works perfect. Just to confirm: `ObjectDataSource1.SelectMethod = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath);` in onpageload/oninit function. Cheers

Comment: I've a bit more complexity. In this UC I have a multiview eg. my UC shows all people who have a certain flag in the DB. In my MV I need to show all those without that flag in another tab. Can I just pass a parameter to the generic UC to read the page name (as above) but with the word "not-"? e.g.`<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0"><asp:View ID="flag" runat="server" ><uc1:GenericUC ID="Flagged" runat="server" /></asp:View><asp:View ID="non-flag" runat="server"><uc2:GenericUC ID="NotFlagged" runat="server" NegatedFlag ="non" /></asp:View></asp:MultiView>`

Comment: Then in the code behind the UC:`public String NegatedFlag {get; set;}`

Comment: Tried that and it worked `NegatedFlag + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath)`
In case that helps anyone else